# JSON Data - Colour green if value is above 0%

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, conditional-statements

How would you render the value in '24hr-btcusdt' green if above 0%

**Script**

```
async function getPriceBTCUSDT() {
     const response = await fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT");
     const data = await response.json();
     const { prevClosePrice, priceChangePercent } = data;

     document.getElementById('price-btcusdt').textContent = prevClosePrice;
     document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt').textContent = priceChangePercent;

     }

     getPriceBTCUSDT();

     setInterval(getPriceBTCUSDT, 1000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-block-3">
   <div class="text-block-2"><span class="currency-title">USDT</span> <span class="currency-symbol">$</span><strong id="price-btcusdt" class="rates">11,794.00</strong></div>
<div id="24hr-btcusdt" class="_24hr-rolling">-1.84<span class="percent-symbol">%</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply add this line in your async function

```
 if(priceChangePercent>0){
  document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt').style.color='green'
  }
```

```js
async function getPriceBTCUSDT() {
     const response = await fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT");
     const data = await response.json();
     const { prevClosePrice, priceChangePercent } = data;
  if(priceChangePercent>0){
  document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt').style.color='green'
  }
     document.getElementById('price-btcusdt').textContent = prevClosePrice;
     document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt').textContent = priceChangePercent;
     

     }

     getPriceBTCUSDT();

     setInterval(getPriceBTCUSDT, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="div-block-3">
   <div class="text-block-2"><span class="currency-title">USDT</span> <span class="currency-symbol">$</span><strong id="price-btcusdt" class="rates">11,794.00</strong></div>
<span id="24hr-btcusdt" class="_24hr-rolling">1.84</span>%
</div>
```